# Software for graph colorability

Tags: windows, open-source, web-apps, library, ios

Is there a function (compiled?) to determine graph colorability or chromatic number, whereby the input is a given graph, in some suitable format such as Graph6, and the output is either True or False, if the question is a k-colorability question, or a positive integer, if the required output is the chromatic number of the graph?

I have several coloring problems in mind, but specifically, one which involves a graph with 105 vertices, which is 12-regular and has clique number 5.  I would like to determine its chromatic number, which is either 6 or 7, or more specifically, whether it is 6-colorable.

Ideally, the function is either stand alone, running in Windows, or a compiled function which can be called from an environment such as Mathematica.  Whatever I have available at the moment cannot solve the problem, it seems.

Comment: The colorability of the graph with 105 vertices got settled after several days of computation with IGraph. However, the question is still valid, as this is one of several problems in the list for which the tools available to me at the moment hang.